# UIStepper inside UITableViewCell Goes Problematic When Tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to present a UIStepper in a row of a UITableView(only the second row - see the image below).

Therefore I implemented `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` like below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OptionCell")!
  let debugModeOptionType = DebugModeOptionsType(rawValue: indexPath.row)

  switch(debugModeOptionType!) {
  case .DummyCurrentLocation:
    cell.textLabel!.text = "Dummy current location"
  case .StepLength:
    cell.textLabel!.text = "Step Length: \(stepLength)"

    // create a UIStepper
    let stepper = UIStepper(frame: CGRectMake(220, 10, 100, 10))

    // customize UIStepper
    stepper.autorepeat = true
    stepper.value = stepLength
    stepper.minimumValue = 0.1
    stepper.stepValue = 0.02
    stepper.maximumValue = 1.5

    stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(adjustStepLength(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)

    // add UIStepper into the cell
    stepper.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.contentView.addSubview(stepper)

    case .TrueHeading:
      cell.textLabel?.text = "True Heading: \(trueHeading)"
    case .MagneticHeading:
      cell.textLabel?.text = "Magnetic Heading: \(magneticHeading)"
    case .HeadingAccuracy:
      cell.textLabel?.text = "Heading Accuracy: \(headingAccuracy)"
    case .CurrentDirection:
      cell.textLabel?.text = "Current Direction: \(currentDirection)"
    case .DrawWalking:
      cell.textLabel?.text = "Draw walking while navigating"
    }

    if selectedDebugModeOptions.contains(debugModeOptionType!) {
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    } else {
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

    return cell
}
```

However when I touch the UIStepper on a real device(this does not happen inside the simulator) the following happens:

[image: UIStepper inside UITableViewCell]

When this happens, the other cells' UISteppers start flashing as well. Why does such a problem occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say why this happening only on a real device, but because table view cells are reused, you have to be careful when adding elements to the cells programmatically, because those elements (such as your stepper) will be spread to other cells as the cells are reused.

There are (at least) two ways you can deal with this:

1. Check for the presence of a stepper after you dequeue a reusable cell and remove it if it is on a row that doesn't need a stepper.  You could do this by giving the stepper a unique tag number (such as `123`) and then search for subviews with that tag and remove them.

   ```
   let stepperTagNumber = 123
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OptionCell")!
   let debugModeOptionType = DebugModeOptionsType(rawValue: indexPath.row)

   if let stepper = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(stepperTagNumber) {
       // We have a stepper but don't need it, so remove it.
       if debugModeOptionType != .StepLength {
           stepper.removeFromSuperview()
       }
   } else {
       // We don't have a stepper, but need one.
       if debugModeOptionType == .StepLength {
           // create a UIStepper
           let stepper = UIStepper(frame: CGRectMake(220, 10, 100, 10))
           stepper.tag = stepperTagNumber  // This is key, don't forget to set the tag

           // customize UIStepper
           stepper.autorepeat = true
           stepper.value = stepLength
           stepper.minimumValue = 0.1
           stepper.stepValue = 0.02
           stepper.maximumValue = 1.5

           stepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(adjustStepLength(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)

           // add UIStepper into the cell
           stepper.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           cell.contentView.addSubview(stepper)
       }
   }
   ```

   OR:
2. Create a second prototype cell for your tableview (called `"OptionCellWithStepper"`).  Add the stepper to that cell in your storyboard.  Then, when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, use `"OptionCellWithStepper"` for case `.StepLength` and use identifier `"OptionCell"` for all the other cases.  Doing it this way, you don't have to programmatically add the stepper, and you don't have to remember to remove it for the other cells.

   ```
   let debugModeOptionType = DebugModeOptionsType(rawValue: indexPath.row)
   let cellID = (debugModeOptionType == .StepLength) ? "OptionCellWithStepper" : "OptionCell"
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID)!
   ```